# Combine INSERT, UPDATE and WHERE NOT EXISTS in one query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine INSERT, UPDATE and WHERE NOT EXISTS in one and the same query. 
What I have at the moment is these two queries that works as expected separately

```
INSERT INTO settings (mid) SELECT '123' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT mid FROM settings WHERE mid='123');
UPDATE settings SET vote = CONCAT_WS(',', vote, '22') WHERE mid = '123'
```

What I am trying to achieve is combine them together, so I can bother the db once

What I have is a table with two columns: **mid** that stores the unique user id, that column is also a primary, and another column that is called **vote** that stores the user votes in a comma separated order.

So, my aim here is to first check is the user is having a row already created for him (if not to create it) and then if the row exists to add the new vote **22**  in my example to the list.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to look into the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` form of insert.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look... although not sure how to do it